# rails 4 database.yml schema_search_path with hyphen

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-4

In my database.yml file I specify that I am looking for a particular database schema (data-mart) however when I run `rake db:schema:dump` I get an error:

```
    ActiveRecord::StatmentInvalid: PG::SyntaxError: ERROR: syntax error at or near "-" 
LINE 1: SET Search_path TO data-mart
                               ^
```

Obviously it doesn't like the hyphen, so how can I fix this? I cannot change the schema name. And I have also tried surrounding it with quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just needed to add it like this:

```
'"data-mart"'
```